# Не активный скроллбар при открытой модалке (не скрыть а именно не активный), как?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой что необходимо сделать скроллбар именно не активным т.к. при скрытии скроллбара сайт разъезжается.
И в целом не вижу смысла делать всем элементам (боди и прочим стики элементам падинги).

Вот идеальный пример того что хочу это на сайте apple.com если кликнуть по поиску, то скроллбар как бы остаётся и из него только пропадает сам бегунок и  получается аналогичный эффект как при overflow:hidden, но при этом сайт не дергается на эти самые 10/13/16 пикселей.

Попытался посмотреть как у них это реализовано, но понять не смог... Возможно js или еще как-то...
В гугле искал ничего толкового не смог найти, все советы просто скрыть скроллбар и всё.

Comment: Вообще у ссылок в меню есть padding'и, а у меню нет своей высоты(height: auto) и когда мы прячем списки меню у него (height: 0) и сайт съезжает, в данном случае нужно самой меню задать min-height. Или как сделано в apple для меню задать position: fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

добавьте в css:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Опередил.)) А у `body` при этом `overflow:hidden` и высота 100%

Comment: Да действительно что-то получается, но есть несколько нюансов :-)

Получается модалка находится в футере, и если у боди стоит 100% , то скролл так же остаётся, если убрать height то сайт прокручивается к шапке, но со скроллбаром выходит нужный эффект...

Вот как-то еще сдлеать этот нюанс :-)